# Using a Storyboard to animate a 3D object

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'm working with 3D objects in C# and I'm stuck trying to animate a cube to rotate on its own axis. Futhermore I need to be able to control the direction of the rotation and be able to pause the animation.

My current aproach is to create a Storyboard and try to access a "cube" object defined on XAML but with no avail.
Could anybody point me out what I'm doing wrong?

```
    this.RegisterName("cube", cube);    
    myStoryboard = new Storyboard(); 
    RotateTransform3D myRotateTransform = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), 0));
    Rotation3DAnimation myRotationAnimation =  new Rotation3DAnimation(Rotation,AnimationSpeed);
    myRotationAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
    myRotateTransform.Rotation.BeginAnimation(AxisAngleRotation3D.AxisProperty, myVectorAnimation);
    myStoryboard.Children.Add(myRotationAnimation);
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(myRotationAnimation, "cube");
    Storyboard.SetTarget(myRotationAnimation,cube.Transform);
    myStoryboard.Begin();
```

The error this code yield is:

```
Cannot animate '(0)' on an immutable object instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say to no avail, in which situation are you right now?
If you are currently encountering an exception at the start of your program, my guess would be to try to define your `Storyboard` in xaml or conversely your cube in c# and call the `RegisterName` method of your `FrameworkElement`.
If not, please elaborate.

Comment: At compile this error arrises on the myStoryboard.Begin() line:
`Cannot animate '(0)' on an immutable object instance.` 

I have also tried to animate the rotation using AxisAngleRotation3D and casting .BeginAnimation(); on that object, but I couldn't handle the changes in rotation gracefully (nor correctly, the animation returned to the original position when stoping the .BeginAnimation).

Comment: I think the problem is coming from `Storyboard.SetTarget(myRotationAnimation,cube.Transform);`           Check out this link, it might help you: [How to rotate a cube](http://www.codegod.com/wpf-3d-animations-and-textures-AID439.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for declaring the StoryBoard in XAML (as you can create what you want very easily in Blend, or create it all in XAMl and then adjust it in C#, saves having to create all of it in code (which is a nightmare)).

Here is a cube in XAML

I do a rotating 3d cube over here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30078/WPF-A-3D-screensaver-written-in-WPF